# Find Current open Cursors in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

What is the query to find the no. of current open cursors in an Oracle Instance?

Also, what is the accuracy/update frequency of this data?

---

I am using Oracle 10gR2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
--total cursors open, by session
select a.value, s.username, s.sid, s.serial#
from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$session s
where a.statistic# = b.statistic#  and s.sid=a.sid
and b.name = 'opened cursors current';
```

I'm not sure but it should be live data.

From: http://www.orafaq.com/node/758

Answer (score 1):

`select name, value from v$parameter where upper(name) in ('OPEN_CURSORS') order by name;`